# Configure eclipse to perform different tasks on save

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I migrated my projects to use the Gradle builds for all actions (building, testing, etc). When I save in eclipse, it builds with the default eclipse actions. Is there a way to change eclipse's behavior so that when I hit the save button or Ctrl-S it will run `gradle build`?

Answer (score 0):

In the Project Properties on the Builders page you can control which builders are run when the project changes. You can disable existing builder and add new one using either Ant or running a program.